# Length of values in a Scala Map

Tags: scala

I have a simple map as below

```
val myMap = Map("A" -> "AB300","B" -> "XI134","C" -> null)
```

I would like to validate the length of a particular key and would like to return the value as string (and not as `Option` . I tried the following

```
myMap.getOrElse("A",null).toString.length
val res50: Int = 5
```

This works fine. But obviously, doesn't handle for null data

```
myMap.getOrElse("C",null).toString.length 
//Null pointer Exception
```

Is there a way to handle null too? The expectation is length for a null value should return zero (may be replacing null with space or something)

Answer (score 1):

You almost never need to use `null`s in Scala, `Option` is great I don't see why you are insisting on not using it. Anyway, this is probably what you're looking for:

```scala
myMap.get("C")
  .flatMap(Option.apply) // since some values are null in your map
  .fold(ifEmpty = 0)(s => s.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
util.Try(myMap("D").length).getOrElse(0)
```

Comment: Does this work? I don't think length method is function that can be directly used on map.
Just tried this and it threw - `value length is not a member of Any` as length can be applied only on String

Comment: It works on your example `myMap`